# Importing a function from a .py file

Tags: python, function

I work in a .ipybn file, but i want to import a function from a .py file.

My code is:

`from function1 import my_function`

However, I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

How can I fix this? P.s the files are in the same folder.

Comment: There is a syntax error in the module you are importing

Comment: You could use some automated syntax checkers to avoid this kind of error, if you are a vim user syntastic is one option (https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error when the file's source code ended before all the blocks in it are completed. For example, if in your file is:

```
a = input("> ")
if a == 'yes':
print("hello")
```

As you can see, you tell the program to proceed to print before the if statement is completed.

Answer (score 1):

> unexpected EOF while parsing

It was able to open the file, but not parse the content correctly. I would start by checking indentations (spaces vs tabs, # of spaces), quotes, colons.

Something to try is executing python from the command line and importing there. That will eliminate iPython/Jupyter notebook as a variable.